# JPA, EJB, Spring - How to work with lazy fetching?

Tags: spring, jpa, ejb

I have a Spring bean which is basically a Controller. I have an EJB which is in different Jar. I am retrieving db objects through this EJB which uses JPA (Hibernate as the provider). I am injecting this EJB in my Spring bean and retrieving db objects. The problem I am facing, lazy association is not working.

I am getting LazyInitializationException. Could not initialize proxy - no Session.

I am using openSessionInViewInterceptor in my Spring servlet but no luck.

Can anybody please help me regarding this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That isn't going to work. You have a spring managed entity manager and one with the EJB container. That isn't going to work, basically it might even work against you as you are now always opening, at least, 2 connections to your database.